# How to save icon / bookmark to iPhone home screen for Google Sheets?

Tags: iphone, applications, google-apps

On my Android Pixel 3, I was able to save a specific file from Google Sheets to my home screen.

I can then click that bookmark, and it opens the Sheets app directly to that file.

How can I accomplish the same thing on iPhone 6S?

Comment: Related: [How can I quickly open a text file from the iPhone's home screen?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/92475/274411), [Is it possible to create an icon on home screen to a specific note?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/8595/274411)

Comment: What iOS update are you running?

Comment: If you're running some recent update, you can add widgets from Google Drive showing recently opened files.

Answer (score 3):

#### Use a Shortcut

This can be achieved with a single action Shortcut that is saved to the Home Screen.  Following are the very simple steps to create this action.

**1. [Create a new Shortcut](https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/create-a-custom-shortcut-apd84c576f8c/ios) and name it appropriately** (i.e. “Open Foo.bar”)

**2. From the *Documents* Category, select the action *Open File***

**3. Add the File and (optional) App selections.**  Within the Action definition, there will be two fields:

- File.  Tap on this to select the file you want to open
- App.  This is preset to “Default App”, but you can select the application you want to open the file in.

[image]

For this example, I am opening an Excel Spreadsheet (closest to Google Sheets; I don’t use Google products).  Here I specify the file “AMEX Pay With Points Analysis.xls” and the app to open it in, *Excel* (though it would work with the “Default App”).

[image]

**4.  Save this shortcut to the Home Screen.**

When you open this from the Home Screen, it will launch Excel with the file loaded.

[image]

**5. Duplicate this Shortcut for every file you want on your Home Screen.**

Comment: This got me on the right track (I didn't know about the Shortcuts app), so +1. But I needed https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/create-a-custom-shortcut-apd84c576f8c/ios and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/384348/53510 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/420899/53510 too.